# Fusing the ResNet-50 and YOLO algorithms for enhanced deep learning object detection

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I am attempting to build a custom object detector that detects weeds in images taken by UAS (details have been spared to simplify the question). I have been experimenting with the YOLO algorithms as well as using the models in the [TensorFlow 2 Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md), as there are many options available for the CNNs to be constructed.

Doing a literature review, I have come across a very interesting paper ([Abdulsalam and Aouf 2020](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9183325)) on this topic, presented at a conference in France. The researchers did something very interesting when they fused the YOLO algorithm with the ResNet-50 algorithm:

"This function approach involves adopting the outcome of one of the layers from ResNet-50 as an input to YOLOv2. This network layer from the ResNet-50 is specified as for feature extraction in YOLOv2. In this work, we used the ReLU (activation_49_relu) layer for the feature extraction layer. This layer will now be the input of YOLOv2."

Doing this, they were able to obtain a very high classification accuracy when mapping weed infestations. Looking at the TensorFlow Zoo, there is an option to use a pre-trained model (Faster R-CNN ResNet50 V1 1024x1024) that uses the ResNet-50 architecture. Code is below:

```
# Faster R-CNN with Resnet-50 (v1)
# Trained on COCO, initialized from Imagenet classification checkpoint

# This config is TPU compatible.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 90
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        width: 1024
        height: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet50_keras'
      batch_norm_trainable: true
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        share_box_across_classes: true
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
    use_static_shapes: true
    use_matmul_crop_and_resize: true
    clip_anchors_to_image: true
    use_static_balanced_label_sampler: true
    use_matmul_gather_in_matcher: true
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 64
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 100000
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .04
          total_steps: 100000
          warmup_learning_rate: .013333
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "classification"
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_hue {
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_contrast {
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_saturation {
    }
  }

  data_augmentation_options {
     random_square_crop_by_scale {
      scale_min: 0.6
      scale_max: 1.3
    }
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  use_bfloat16: true  # works only on TPUs
}
train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/label_map.txt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/train2017-?????-of-00256.tfrecord"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/label_map.txt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/val2017-?????-of-00032.tfrecord"
  }
}
```

What exactly would I have to do in order to integrate this ResNet-50 algorithm structure in the YOLO algorithm, as was done in this example?

Here is the backbone file for the YOLOv4 file, as was able to get doing a `pip install yolov4`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, Sequential

from .common import YOLOConv2D


class _ResBlock(Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        filters_1: int,
        filters_2: int,
        activation: str = "mish",
        kernel_regularizer=None,
    ):
        super(_ResBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=filters_1,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv2 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=filters_2,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.add = layers.Add()

    def call(self, x):
        ret = self.conv1(x)
        ret = self.conv2(ret)
        x = self.add([x, ret])
        return x


class ResBlock(Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        filters_1: int,
        filters_2: int,
        iteration: int,
        activation: str = "mish",
        kernel_regularizer=None,
    ):
        super(ResBlock, self).__init__()
        self.iteration = iteration
        self.sequential = Sequential()
        for _ in range(self.iteration):
            self.sequential.add(
                _ResBlock(
                    filters_1=filters_1,
                    filters_2=filters_2,
                    activation=activation,
                    kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
                )
            )

    def call(self, x):
        return self.sequential(x)


class CSPResNet(Model):
    """
    Cross Stage Partial connections(CSP)
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        filters_1: int,
        filters_2: int,
        iteration: int,
        activation: str = "mish",
        kernel_regularizer=None,
    ):
        super(CSPResNet, self).__init__()
        self.pre_conv = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=filters_1,
            kernel_size=3,
            strides=2,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

        # Do not change the order of declaration
        self.part2_conv = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=filters_2,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

        self.part1_conv1 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=filters_2,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.part1_res_block = ResBlock(
            filters_1=filters_1 // 2,
            filters_2=filters_2,
            iteration=iteration,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.part1_conv2 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=filters_2,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

        self.concat1_2 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)

        self.post_conv = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=filters_1,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.pre_conv(x)

        part2 = self.part2_conv(x)

        part1 = self.part1_conv1(x)
        part1 = self.part1_res_block(part1)
        part1 = self.part1_conv2(part1)

        x = self.concat1_2([part1, part2])

        x = self.post_conv(x)
        return x


class SPP(Model):
    """
    Spatial Pyramid Pooling layer(SPP)
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(SPP, self).__init__()
        self.pool1 = layers.MaxPooling2D((13, 13), strides=1, padding="same")
        self.pool2 = layers.MaxPooling2D((9, 9), strides=1, padding="same")
        self.pool3 = layers.MaxPooling2D((5, 5), strides=1, padding="same")
        self.concat = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)

    def call(self, x):
        return self.concat([self.pool1(x), self.pool2(x), self.pool3(x), x])


class CSPDarknet53(Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        activation0: str = "mish",
        activation1: str = "leaky",
        kernel_regularizer=None,
    ):
        super(CSPDarknet53, self).__init__(name="CSPDarknet53")
        self.conv0 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=32,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation0,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

        self.res_block1 = CSPResNet(
            filters_1=64,
            filters_2=64,
            iteration=1,
            activation=activation0,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.res_block2 = CSPResNet(
            filters_1=128,
            filters_2=64,
            iteration=2,
            activation=activation0,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.res_block3 = CSPResNet(
            filters_1=256,
            filters_2=128,
            iteration=8,
            activation=activation0,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

        self.res_block4 = CSPResNet(
            filters_1=512,
            filters_2=256,
            iteration=8,
            activation=activation0,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

        self.res_block5 = CSPResNet(
            filters_1=1024,
            filters_2=512,
            iteration=4,
            activation=activation0,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

        self.conv72 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=512,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation1,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv73 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=1024,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation1,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv74 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=512,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation1,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

        self.spp = SPP()

        self.conv75 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=512,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation1,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv76 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=1024,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation1,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv77 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=512,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation1,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv0(x)

        x = self.res_block1(x)
        x = self.res_block2(x)
        x = self.res_block3(x)

        route1 = x

        x = self.res_block4(x)

        route2 = x

        x = self.res_block5(x)
        x = self.conv72(x)
        x = self.conv73(x)
        x = self.conv74(x)

        x = self.spp(x)

        x = self.conv75(x)
        x = self.conv76(x)
        x = self.conv77(x)

        route3 = x

        return (route1, route2, route3)


class CSPDarknet53Tiny(Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        activation: str = "leaky",
        kernel_regularizer=None,
    ):
        super(CSPDarknet53Tiny, self).__init__(name="CSPDarknet53Tiny")
        self.conv0 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=32,
            kernel_size=3,
            strides=2,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv1 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=64,
            kernel_size=3,
            strides=2,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

        self.conv2 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=64,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv3 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=32,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv4 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=32,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.concat3_4 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
        self.conv5 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=64,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.concat2_5 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
        self.maxpool5 = layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")

        self.conv6 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=128,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv7 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=64,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv8 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=64,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.concat7_8 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
        self.conv9 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=128,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.concat6_9 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
        self.maxpool9 = layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")

        self.conv10 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=256,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv11 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=128,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.conv12 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=128,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.concat11_12 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
        self.conv13 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=256,
            kernel_size=1,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )
        self.concat10_13 = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
        self.maxpool13 = layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")

        self.conv14 = YOLOConv2D(
            filters=512,
            kernel_size=3,
            activation=activation,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
        )

    def call(self, x):
        x1 = self.conv0(x)
        x1 = self.conv1(x1)

        x1 = self.conv2(x1)
        _, x2 = tf.split(x1, 2, axis=-1)
        x2 = self.conv3(x2)
        x3 = self.conv4(x2)
        x3 = self.concat3_4([x3, x2])
        x3 = self.conv5(x3)
        x3 = self.concat2_5([x1, x3])
        x1 = self.maxpool5(x3)

        x1 = self.conv6(x1)
        _, x2 = tf.split(x1, 2, axis=-1)
        x2 = self.conv7(x2)
        x3 = self.conv8(x2)
        x3 = self.concat7_8([x3, x2])
        x3 = self.conv9(x3)
        x3 = self.concat6_9([x1, x3])
        x1 = self.maxpool9(x3)

        x1 = self.conv10(x1)
        _, x2 = tf.split(x1, 2, axis=-1)
        x2 = self.conv11(x2)
        x3 = self.conv12(x2)
        x3 = self.concat11_12([x3, x2])
        route1 = self.conv13(x3)
        x3 = self.concat10_13([x1, route1])
        x1 = self.maxpool13(x3)

        route2 = self.conv14(x1)

        return route1, route2
```